# Как правильно конвертировать binary столбец в string?

Tags: python, строки, sql-server, pandas, форматирование

Как правильно конвертировать `binary` столбец в `string`?

Дело в том, что столбец, откуда тянутся данные в binary, использую методы `str`, `to_string`, попадают так - `b'\x80\xc6\x10`K\xa8\x95\xd8\x11\xe6\r\x...`, но в самой БД` 0x80C610604BA895D811E60DE464C54D74` (откуда тянется).

Если не использовать эти методы, то попадают как `\x80C610604BA895D811E60DE464C54D74`.

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой ?

```
engine = create_engine('...')
df = pd.read_sql("""Select id_bin from table1""",engine)
local_port = str(server.local_bind_port)
df.index +=1
df['id_bin']=str(df['id_bin'])
engine1 = create_engine('..')
pd1 = engine1.execute("""Truncate table table2""")
df.to_sql('table2',con=engine1,if_exists='append',index_label='id')
```

Comment: С каким типом БД вы работаете? И какой тип данных у столбца id_bin в таблице?

Comment: @MaxU Тянутся данные с MSSQL загружаются данные в  Postgres , id_bin тип varchar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df = pd.read_sql("""select convert(varchar(1000), id_bin, 2) from table1""", engine)
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло .  Но в моем случае convert(varchar(1000), id_bin, 1)

Comment: @fikos, был рад помочь)